# Property 'MktoForms2' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, marketo

Getting error:(Property 'MktoForms2' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis') on using react with typescript

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-sj11.marketo.com", "XXX-XXX-XXX", 1608);
}, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

You are likely to get that error if the actual `MktoForms2` library hasn't been loaded yet. That should be loaded like this, *before* you try and make the `loadForm` call..

```
<script src="//app-xyz.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.js"></script>
```

The domain that the script gets loaded from is specific to your Marketo instance, but you can find the documentation for the form library here: https://developers.marketo.com/javascript-api/forms/